# SWITCH statement syntax error

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I get this error :
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', expecting endswitch (T_ENDSWITCH) or case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) in /var/www/mel-suhaib/application/modules/default/views/scripts/user/user.phtml on line 244`

```
<?php switch ($ext): ?>

                     line244++>     <?php case  "pdf": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "docx": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "zip": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "xlsx": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "pptx": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "rar": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "xls": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "jpg": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "ppt": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "doc": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case  "3gp": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "mp4": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php case "png": ?>
                                    <img class="timeline-img pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <?php break; ?>
                                    <?php endswitch; ?>
```

Comment: My eyes are bleeding from looking at this code. You really shouldn't be jumping in and out of PHP like that.

Comment: use this way
 switch ($ext){
}
and u have used  switch ($ext):

Comment: There's HTML output between your `switch()` and the first `case:`

Comment: Solved I should instead say  <?php switch ($ext): case "pdf":?> rather than <?php switch ($ext): ?>
<?php case  "pdf": ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I should instead say:

```
<?php switch ($ext): case "pdf": ?>
```

Rather than

```
<?php switch ($ext): ?> <?php case "pdf": ?>
```